# Get bounding rectangle for treeitem including icon

Tags: vb6, treeview

I have a requirement of getting bounding rectangle for a treeitem in a treeview. The treeview control used is a VB6 treeview (TreeView20WndClass).

I came across TVM_GETITEMRECT. But, it says that if wParam is true, it will get rectangle only for the text part and if it is false, it will get rectangle for the entire line that the item occupies in the tree-view control.

But, I want to get the rectangle the region including both text part and icon. I am unable to find a way for this.

Or is it possible to get the rectangle for the icon?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Regards,

kvk938

Comment: A google search turned up [this page](http://www.devx.com/vb2themax/Tip/18992). In the code comments, the author says, "If the 3rd argument is True it returns the bounding rectangle for the text portion of the node, otherwise it returns the bounding rectangle for the entire row."

Comment: @C-PoundGuru, I already know that the 3rd argument makes the difference and I have already mentioned that in my question. But, my requirement is to get the rectangle for the region that includes both text and icon or at least the rectangle for the icon.

Comment: Perhaps I misread or misunderstood, "...returns the bounding rectangle for the entire row." Wouldn't the entire row include everything--text and icon?  You might get a response if you [edit] your question with the actual code you tried.